# Realm. How to add new entity to database?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I'm new in Realm and I'm trying to create new entity in Realm database.
First of all, I have a FolderItem class

```kotlin
data class FolderItem(
    val id: Int,
    var name: String,
    var postIds: List<FavoriteId>,
    var isChosen: Boolean
)
```

and according to Realm docs I decided to transform it to

```kotlin
open class FolderItem(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int = 0,
    var name: String = "",
    var postIds: RealmList<FavoriteId> = RealmList(),
    var isChosen: Boolean = false
): RealmObject()
```

where FavoriteId is

```kotlin
open class FavoriteId(
    val postId: Int = 0,
    val wpId: Int? = null
): RealmObject()
```

But each time when I'm trying to build the project, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':logic:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I also found out that the error occurs as soon as I write: `: RealmObject()` and no matter what I write next.

Can you please help me figure out what the problem is?

P.S. Other Realm logic in project works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your gradle.properties file:

```
kapt.use.worker.api=false
kapt.incremental.apt=false
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. Thanks to these two lines I found a bug. it was that I used the keyword **val** instead of **var** omg